# AnalysisException when dropping a hive database using spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

#### Environment

- spark 3.0.0
- hive metastore (standalone) 3.0.0
- mysql 8 as the metastore db

#### Problem

- Every time I try to drop a database in the metastore via spark, I get AnalysisException and I don't know what is causing it or whether the drop operation is succeeding in it's entirety

#### Example

```
  spark.sql(f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myDb LOCATION 'shared-metastore-location/myDb.db'")
  ################
  # DB creation succeeds and I can view the db in the metastore, add tables etc
  ################
  spark.sql(f"DROP DATABASE myDb CASCADE")
  ################
  AnalysisException: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Unable to clean up java.sql.SQLException: The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin.\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1335)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2108)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1245)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyStatement.java:117)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyStatement.java)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.txn.TxnHandler.cleanupRecords(TxnHandler.java:2741)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.AcidEventListener.onDropDatabase(AcidEventListener.java:52)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreListenerNotifier$21.notify(MetaStoreListenerNotifier.java:85)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreListenerNotifier.notifyEvent(MetaStoreListenerNotifier.java:264)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreListenerNotifier.notifyEvent(MetaStoreListenerNotifier.java:326)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreListenerNotifier.notifyEvent(MetaStoreListenerNotifier.java:364)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.drop_database_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1537)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.drop_database(HiveMetaStore.java:1575)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.drop_database(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$drop_database.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:14352)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$drop_database.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:14336)\n\tat org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor$1.run(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:111)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor$1.run(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:107)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor.process(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n);'
```

- Despite the Exception, the database does disappear after I run this code. And if I try to run the drop command a second time, I get a different exception saying that the database doesn't exist. But, I have no idea whether the operation has succeeded in its entirety or whether it's leaving a mess behind. I'm not familiar enough with Hive to know what should be deleted in the metastore to completely delete a db
- I seem to get the same result whether I have tables in the db or not. I've also tried dropping the table without cascade. Same result